# How do I test swap pair in Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I used the factory contract to create the pair contract, how do I get an instance of the pair contract in Hardhat. Used to query the LP value of an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the question and the content is far different.

If you're using the factory, then there's a function getPair, which returns you the address of the pair.

```
function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
```

When you have the pair address, you can fetch the number of tokens in the pair using [getReserve function](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/pair#getreserves)